# How to use same animation.value on diiferent widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-web

I am new to flutter, can any one please tell me how can use multiple instances of `animation` to use separate `animation.value` in different widgets e.g I am using it here as `width: animation.value` 
any help is welcomed

```
.....
    controller =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    animation = Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 200).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    .......
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: <Widget>[MouseRegion(
                            onEnter: (hovered) {
                              controller.forward();
                            },
                            onExit: (hovered) {
                              controller.reverse();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  AnimatedContainer(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    color: Colors.red.shade300,
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                    curve: Curves.decelerate,
                                    height: 5,
                                    width: animation.value,
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "About",
                                      softWrap: false,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          MouseRegion(
                            onEnter: (hovered) {
                              controller.forward();
                            },
                            onExit: (hovered) {
                              controller.reverse();
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  AnimatedContainer(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    color: Colors.red.shade300,
                                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                    curve: Curves.decelerate,
                                    height: 5,
                                    width: animation.value,
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "About",
                                      softWrap: false,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),],);}
```

Comment: Are your animations occurring over the same period of time. You could use simple mathematical functions to change the behavior a specific widget.(Ex. if animation.value was moving forward, you could use 200-animation.value to move backward in a separate widget). Creating multiple instances of animation is expensive and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply...The goal here is to use same hover animation on multiple menu item and the animation is triggered on mouse event. In the example code I just simply used 'animation.value' for the width of animated container but what I am trying to figure out is to find a way to use same animation and avoid making multiple copies of Animation and AnimationController. I have never used 'Key' but I think it can be used to distinguish.

Comment: Oh, so if I'm understanding this correctly you also want your widgets reverse this animation when exited, if you want multiple animations to be moving forward and backwards at the same time with different offsets, you will might need to use multiple instances of animation.